# Android Dynamic Button - Same arithmatic operator displayed again and again and also not formatted - Its worked

Tags: android, button

I am new to android. I want to display the 5 numbers in the Button.  And also needs to display the arithmetic buttons also like below

```
    14     12      13     12    11      ( These number to be displayed in the   button )


          +   -  *   /               (  These arithmetic button also displayed in button)
```

I want to display like above dynamically.  And i am using this code, but it displaying like below.( not displaying +, - *, / )

```
     /  14
     /  12
     /  13
     /  12        
     /  11
```

1. I want to display like mentioned initially and also i want listen the button clicked
2. Its displaying Normal buttons, how i can display as like Graphic buttons. ( so that it will give more attraction)

Please find the code below.

```
setContentView(R.layout.dynamically_create_view_element);

final LinearLayout lm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearMain);

// create the layout params that will be used to define how your
// button will be displayed
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);



for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
{   
    // Create LinearLayout
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    // Create TextView
    final Button btn1 = new Button(this);
    // Give button an ID
    btn1.setId(1);
    btn1.setText("+");
    btn1.setId(2);
    btn1.setText("-");
    btn1.setId(3);
    btn1.setText("*");
    btn1.setId(4);
    btn1.setText("/");

    // Create Button
    final Button btn = new Button(this);
        // Give button an ID
        btn.setId(j+1);
        int random1 = (int )(Math.random() * 20 + 1);
        btn.setText(""+numbers[j]+"");
        // set the layoutParams on the button
        btn.setLayoutParams(params);

        final int index = j;
        // Set click listener for button
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.i("TAG", "index :" + index);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Clicked Button Index :" + index, 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    //Create four

       //Add button to LinearLayout
        ll.addView(btn1);
        ll.addView(btn);
       //Add button to LinearLayout defined in XML
        lm.addView(ll);  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok there are multiple issues with your code:

First, you're getting the below result

```
/ 14
/ 12
/ 13
/ 12
/ 11
```

because inside your `for-loop` you're setting the text of `btn1` to `/` after setting the text of the `Button` to `+` then to `-` and then to `*`.

Also because you're creating a `LinearLayout` for each `Button` you're getting the numbers below each other.

I've taken the liberty to re-write the code a bit into something a bit more generic:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private LinearLayout lm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lm);

        // Create a LinearLayout for each row inside the outer LinearLayout.
        LinearLayout firstRow = new LinearLayout(this);
        firstRow.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        // Create a String array of items you want to add to the inner LinearLayout.
        String[] itemsToAddToFirstRow = { "14", "12", "13", "12", "11" };
        createButtonsDynamically(firstRow, itemsToAddToFirstRow);

        String[] itemsToAddToSecondRow = { "+", "-", "*", "/" };
        LinearLayout secondRow = new LinearLayout(this);
        secondRow.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        createButtonsDynamically(secondRow, itemsToAddToSecondRow);
    }

    private void createButtonsDynamically(LinearLayout layoutToAddButtonsTo, String[] itemsToAdd) {
        for (int i = 0; i < itemsToAdd.length; i++) {
            final Button buttonToAdd = new Button(this);
            buttonToAdd.setText(itemsToAdd[i]);
            buttonToAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I was clicked: " + buttonToAdd.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            layoutToAddButtonsTo.addView(buttonToAdd);
        }

        // In the end add all buttons inside the inner LinearLayout to the outer LinearLayout.
        lm.addView(layoutToAddButtonsTo);
    }
}
```

Add your own code to add the ids to the `Button`s.

The end-result will look like this:

[image: Buttons added dynamically in code...]

As far as your **#2.** goes:

You could a background image to your `Button`s by calling `setBackground(Drawable drawable)` for the buttons or you completely re-style the standard `Button`.

Have a go at this [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html) from the official guidelines.

Hope this helps :-)